# Update alterando um valor pelo outro na tabela

Tags: postgresql

Existe alguma forma de usar o where para alterar dois produtos ? por exemplo.

```
UPDATE PRODUTO
SET CODNCM = '09102000'
WHERE descricao = 'ACAFRAO PURO' 'ACAFRAO PURO 250G'
```

entre o açafrão puro e o açafrão puro 2050g  os dois produtos utiliza mesma tributação, como altero esses dois produtos sem gerar outro update

Comment: descricao IN ( 'ACAFRAO PURO', 'ACAFRAO PURO 250G') https://pgdocptbr.sourceforge.io/pg80/functions-comparisons.html#FUNCTIONS-IN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível, sim!

Caso você queira atualizar essas duas descrições, basta utilizar o `or`:

```
UPDATE PRODUTO
SET CODNCM = '09102000'
WHERE descricao = 'ACAFRAO PURO' OR descricao = 'ACAFRAO PURO 250G'
```

Também é possível utilizando `in`:

```
UPDATE PRODUTO
SET CODNCM = '09102000'
WHERE descricao in ('ACAFRAO PURO', 'ACAFRAO PURO 250G')
```

Outra forma possível, caso tenha mais de uma *descricao* a ser modificada, pode usar o `like` (da forma abaixo, todos os produtos que contenham "ACAFRAO" na descrição serão atualizados):

```
UPDATE PRODUTO
SET CODNCM = '09102000'
WHERE descricao LIKE '%ACAFRAO%'
```

Comment: Deu certo, Muito Obrigadoooooo